# Facing error while accessing cassandra data through Solr_query json for datastax.oss dse java driver 4.13.0 version

Tags: solr, cassandra, datastax

*DSE version: 6.7*

As the below code was working fine for DSE java driver version : 1.8.2 with the below code

`Statement selectQuery = QueryBuilder.select().all().from(table) .where(**QueryBuilder.eq**("solr_query", "{"q":"createdat:[2021-10-15T14:03:37.817Z TO 2021-12-15T07:23:14.025Z]","sort":"updatedate desc", "paging":"driver"}")) .setConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.valueOf("LOCAL_ONE")); ResultSet rs= super.getManager().getSession().execute(selectQuery);`

upgrading to DSE java drivers version : 4.13.0
query is:-

`Select selectQuery = selectFrom(table).all().whereColumn("solr_query").isEqualTo(literal("{"q":"createdat:[2021-10-15T14:03:37.817Z TO 2021-12-15T07:23:14.025Z]","sort":"updatedate desc", "paging":"driver"}")); SimpleStatement statement = selectQuery.build().setConsistencyLevel(DefaultConsistencyLevel.valueOf("LOCAL_ONE")); ResultSet rs = this.session.execute(statement );`

*--> **Giving below exception :**

> com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.servererrors.InvalidQueryException: Error on shard 12.345.678.90: Field cache is disabled, set the field=updatedate to be docValues=true and reindex.  Or if the field cache will not exceed the heap usage, then place useFieldCache=true in the request parameters.

- 

I am not sure how to address this.

Comment: It will be difficult to troubleshoot this with you in the Q&A format of the Community so I would recommend that if you have a DSE subscription, request that you log a ticket on the DataStax Support portal https://support.datastax.com/ and attach a Diagnostics Report along with version changes in driver, JDK, application logs, etc., so one of our engineers can analyse it for you. Cheers! We could always follow-up and post the finding here to close the loop.

Comment: what is the DSE version being used? Was there any recent upgrade of DSE server/JDK apart from the Java Driver upgrade from 4.9.0 to 4.13.0?

Comment: @Madhavan datastax Eterprise is 6.7
upgrading dse java drivers from 1.8.2 to 4.13

Comment: Thanks for updating the original question as well as providing the DSE version of 6.7 (still we don't know what is the patch version. For e.g. 6.7.11). Have you already opened a support ticket to provide the other asks around application logs, stack traces, server side diagnostic bundle, minimal codebase to repro, etc.,?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing Solr core rebuilt for concerned shard, the `InvalidQueryException` issue got resolved.
Thanks all for your time on this issue :)

Answer (score 0):

So in looking at the error message...

> set the `field=updatedate` to be `docValues=true` and reindex.

Just wondering, but have you tried this?  This should be a good first step.

Comment: updatedate {docValues:true} is already added with the CREATE SEARCH INDEX script.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I am really curious how did you get this version:

> datastax.oss 4.13.0 version

because it does not look any of the official DSE product version such as 5.0.x. or 6.8.x. There was 4.8.x in the past but never oss 4.13.

Now for the problem itself:
this may apply https://docs.datastax.com/en/upgrade/doc/upgrade/datastax_enterprise/upgdDSE50.html#Preparingtoupgrade

Hard to say because of the misleading DSE versions...

While it is highly recommended to use `docValues` there is also proposed approach with setting `dse.yaml`:

> you can re-enable the field cache (solr_field_cache_enabled: true) to allow running queries but not reindexing.